# Get a list of all elixir modules in IEx

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

To get a list of all functions on a module in IEx I can run:

```
Map.__info__(:functions)
# or
Enum.__info__(:functions)
```

Using the `{Module}.__info__(:functions)` format.

How can I get a list of all the standard lib modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From IEx you can type <kbd>:</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get a list of all available modules.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get all loaded Elixir modules, without erlang modules, run the following in a clean IEx shell:

```
:code.all_loaded() 
|> Enum.filter(fn {mod, _} -> "#{mod}" =~ ~r{^[A-Z]} end)
|> Enum.map(fn {mod, _} -> mod end)

# [Exception, Application, Inspect.Atom, IEx.Pry, Logger.Config, Module, Keyword, ... ]
```

This will also include sub modules like `IEx.Config`, but you can filter them with some  additional mapping:

```
:code.all_loaded() 
|> Enum.filter(fn {mod, _} -> "#{mod}" =~ ~r{^[A-Z]} end)
|> Enum.map(fn {mod, _} -> mod end)
|> Enum.map(fn mod -> hd(Module.split(mod)) end)
|> Enum.uniq

# ["Exception", "Application", "Inspect", "IEx", "Logger", "Module", "Keyword", ... ]
```

Comment: this seems to be what i'm looking for, however there are three dots on the ends that imply there's more to the list. how do i get the whole list?

Comment: Output it with `IO.inspect` or `IO.puts`

Comment: `:erlang.loaded() |> Enum.sort() |> inspect(limit: :infinity) |> IO.puts`

Comment: There is no notion of “submodules” in Elixir. Actually, `IEx.Pry` and `IEx` are two absolutely different modules, knowing nothing about each other.

Comment: after studying the iex source code I came up with this, that gives me more modules (MapSet for instance): `:application.get_key(:elixir, :modules) |> inspect(limit: :infinity) |> IO.puts` . I looked at https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/60f86886c0f66c71790e61d754eada4e9fa0ace5/lib/iex/lib/iex/autocomplete.ex#L507